# Get Quickest 0-60 in Database using PHP or MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

Not sure if this is possible in the slightest, or maybe I'm thinking this too much, but..

I have a huge record set full of track 0-60mph times, and I am trying to find the fastest one, from start ID to end ID, so that I can later display them in a chart showing how long it took the car to speed up.
Is there a MySQL query I can use to find this? or even a PHP statement?

My Database looks a little bit like:

```
--- vws_data ---
id      value (speed)   date
1       1               01/01/2019 12:00:00
2       3               01/01/2019 12:00:01
3       6               01/01/2019 12:00:02
4       10              01/01/2019 12:00:03
5       13              01/01/2019 12:00:04
6       1               01/01/2019 15:00:00
7       4               01/01/2019 15:00:01
8       10              01/01/2019 15:00:02
9       24              01/01/2019 15:00:03
10      29              01/01/2019 15:00:04
11      35              01/01/2019 15:00:05
12      40              01/01/2019 15:00:06
13      44              01/01/2019 15:00:07
14      47              01/01/2019 15:00:08
15      52              01/01/2019 15:00:09
16      56              01/01/2019 15:00:10
17      60              01/01/2019 15:00:11
18      30              01/01/2019 17:20:00
19      31              01/01/2019 17:20:01
20      30              01/01/2019 17:20:02
```

In this example, I would be looking for ID's 6 to 17

**EDIT**

An actual example of my database. (Sensor 0D is Vehicle Speed)
[image: database example]

My database structure is as follows.
[image: database columns]

Comment: `ORDER BY` but since you haven't shown the columns I don't know what on. Don't show what your database "looks a little bit like", show your actual database with `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and some sample data. Hopefully that column is not called, literally `value (speed)`. So could be `ORDER BY value DESC` for values in *descending* order, which is highest (fastest?) first.

Comment: It seems like the usefulness of sql would be severely curtailed were this not possible

Comment: I don't understand what you are looking for?  You say you want the fastest one but then you say you want ID's 6 to 17 which are multiple records.

Comment: So you are looking to sort by value?  Or what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @tadman Question modified with the actual database structure.

Comment: @dmikester1 I am looking for the start and finish of a 0-60 test, which ID 6 is the start and ID 17 is the end. - But I am looking for the fastest one in the entire database.

Comment: Please write that in your original question, because that's not what you wrote up there.

Comment: @dmikester1 I have modified the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189911/discussion-between-dmikester1-and-michael-davison).

Comment: This is probably what you want: `select * vws_data order by value asc limit 1`. That will give you the row with the lowest speed in the 'value' column. Or if you want to return all values, simply remove the limit

Comment: @CarlosGonzález You don't understand what he's looking for.  Essentially he wants sortation by datetime ascending, then find a row that starts with speed 1.  Then look sequentially until he finds a row with value of 60.  The difference between the timestamps of these 2 rows needs to be computed and returned in seconds.

Comment: Also appears from the test data that there are cases where the car never reaches 60, so those ranges need to be skipped/excluded from the looks of it.

Comment: ^ Exactly that, thanks @gview - Except it would be nice to get the data in-between 0-60 too so I can make a graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally managed to get it working by swinging a few variables around while the database was in the `while` loop.

Firstly, I ran through the database, in `DESCENDING` order, looking for all the values containing 60 (end) as well as all the values containing 0 (stop). I then added both start/end times into a variable and counted how many seconds it took to hit 60. If the result was lower than the last one, the `myQuickest` variables would be changed.

```
$myQuickest60Time = 100; // any high number to kick the less than off, 100 just to be safe.

$sql = "SELECT * FROM vws_getdata WHERE sensor = '0D' ORDER BY date DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      if($row["value"] == "60"){ // UP TO SPEED
        $myLookingForEnd = true;
        $my60Start = $row['date'];
      } else if($row['value'] == "0"){
        if($myLookingForEnd == true){
          $myLookingForEnd = false;
          $my60End = $row['date'];

          if($myQuickest60Time > (strtotime($my60Start) - strtotime($my60End))){
            $myQuickest60Time = (strtotime($my60Start) - strtotime($my60End));
            $myQuickest60Start = $my60Start;
            $myQuickest60End = $row['date'];
          }
        }
      }
    }
} else {
    echo "No Data";
}
```

Then, I query the database again, showing only the dates that match the `myQuickest` variables.

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM vws_getdata WHERE sensor = '0D' AND date >= '".$myQuickest60End."' AND date <= '".$myQuickest60Start."' ORDER BY date ASC";
$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);

if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "INNER  -  Value: " . $row2['value'] . "  -  ID: " . $row2['id'] . "  -  Date: " . $row2['date'] . "<br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "<b>INNER  -  NO RESULT</b><br>";
}
```

Comment: Awesome!  Great work figuring it out.  If it answers your question, mark this as the answer.

Comment: Will do, when it lets me (“you cant accept your own answer for 2 days“)

Comment: Aw yes, forgot about that little detail :)